# Dynamic Columns in jquery Datatable

Tags: jquery, angular, datatables, datatables-1.10

I have A requirement in which the The datatable keeps on changing based on each Link .

```
 link1
 link2
```

If i Click on the link1 the datatable need to be created with defined columns and its data ,

if we click Link1  the data will be

```
 var data = [
              [ "Row 1-Field 1", "Row 1-Field 2", "Row 1-Field 3" ],
              [ "Row 2-Field 1", "Row 2-Field 2", "Row 2-Field 3" ]
            ]; 
 var columns = [
                { "title":"One" },
                { "title":"Two" }, 
                { "title":"Three"}
               ];
```

In Link2 the data will be different with different columns

```
 var data = [
              [ "Row 1-Field 1", "Row 1-Field 2", "Row 1-Field 3","Row 1-Field 4","Row 1-Field 5" ],
              [ "Row 2-Field 1", "Row 2-Field 2", "Row 2-Field 3","Row 2-Field 4","Row 2-Field 5" ]
            ]; 
 var columns = [
                { "title":"One" },
                { "title":"Two" }, 
                { "title":"Three"},
                { "title":"Four"}
                { "title":"Five"}
               ];
```

Apart from this , I need to Add in the datatable three links buttons at the end with details,edit and delete link

```
<sa-datatable id="mytable" [options]="options" tableClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
```

```
options = {
  dom: "Bfrtip",
  data: data,
  columns: columns,
  buttons: [
    'copy', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print', 'colvis'
  ],
};
```

I am able to Load only Link1 , But if i Click on Link2  Its not creating the Table with its columns and its data.
Can someone point to me in the right direction ?

Comment: i think you need to some sort of refresh on this.options.data.refresh() after you change its datasource and columns also

Comment: i have changed datasource and columns but its not reflecting in the jquery datatable

Comment: cause you need (i think) to call a refrsh() (or similar) method to force the grid to refesh the data